# Why is the Windows UI responds slowly after being idle for a long time?

Tags: windows, performance, user-interface

I open these applications in my desktop computer:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- IBM Lotus Notes
- Google Chrome

And when it is idle for an hour and I restore the windows, the user interface responds very slowly. My computer auto-lock itself after being idle for 5 minutes. I also minimize the applications using a docklet *(RocketDock)*.

Why is it slowing down and how can I prevent it from slowing?

My OS is Windows XP Professional SP3, Pentum(R) Dual Core @ 2.80 GHz, 1.99 GB of RAM.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your RAM usage, as windows is probably paging (Copying to disk) these memory intensive programs that are idle.

see this post: [How to reduce disk thrashing (paging)?](https://superuser.com/questions/32860/how-to-reduce-disk-thrashing-paging)

Comment: As well, in WinXP, default behaviour is to always keep physical memory as empty as possible. Hence why disabling paging resolves this issue on XP, but doesn't really do much on Vista/7.

Comment: @EKW Should I disable my paging? How can I disable it? Please help.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona With 2gb of RAM, I would definitely not recommend disabling paging. GKoe's answer is a good one - check your memory usage in Task Manager, and upgrade it if your maximum Commit size is greater than your physical memory.